# Проверка на изменение содержимого файла

Tags: python

Такая проблема. У пользователя есть возможность открыть текстовый файл, нажав кнопку. Он может что-то добавить в этот файл или оставить как есть. При этом действия должны заносится в журнал действий: т.е. там будут записи: "username открыл файл" , если пользователь изменил содержимое, то должна быть подпись "username изменил содержимое". Запись об открытии я реализовал, но как сделать об изменении. Т.е. программа должна как-то сравнивать файл до открытия и после его закрытия наверно, и если есть изменения, то записывать это в журнал. Но как это реализовать, никак не доходит. Помогите пожалуйста. Код с фукнцией:

```
def user1(): #Окно пользователя
root4 = Tk()
root4.title('Окно пользователя')
ab = Label(text='О программе', width=40)
but_ch = Button(text='Сменить пароль', width=40, command=lambda: [root4.destroy(), change()])
but_return = Button(text='Назад', width=40, command=lambda: [root4.destroy(), login2()])
but_fl = Button(text='Открыть файл для изменения', width=40, command=lambda: [os.startfile('users\\files\\GGWP.txt'), inf()])
def inf():
    f = open('users' + '\\' + 'actions' + '\\' + 'act.txt', 'a')
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    f.write('Открыт файл, ' + name + ', ' + str(date) + '\n')
    f.close()
ab.pack()   
but_ch.pack()
but_fl.pack()
but_return.pack()
root4.mainloop()
```

Comment: А нужно записывать только сам факт изменения или и какие строки на что поменялись, например?

Answer (score 0):

Можете проверить содержимое файла оператором сравнения `==` после того, как пользователь закрыл файл.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).